# Updating PostGIS layer with the result of intersection

Tags: postgis, intersection, update

I have a PostGIS layer which I would like to intersect with another layer (adjust its borders). The result of the intersection should then become the new PostGIS layer (update the input layer).

I could save the result as a new PostGIS table, but how could I update input PostGIS layer?

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE! We're a little different from other sites; this isn't a discussion forum but a Q&A site. Your questions should as much as possible describe not just what you want to do, but precisely what you have tried and where you are stuck trying that. Please check out our short [tour] for more about how the site works.

Answer (score 0):

Just for the record:
It's not possible to save the result of the intersection in the table that's being intersected.

I saved the result in a temporary PostGIS table and imported it from there.